# How to handle labels in a scripting language I'm writing?

Tags: c, scripting

So I've been stewing over this for a long time, thinking about it. Here's a code example first, and then I'll explain it.

```
:main
    dostuff
    otherlabel

:otherlabel
    dostuff
```

Alright so in this example, main is where the code starts, and it 'calls' the label 'otherlabel'. This is really just a shortcut for a jump command that changes execution to a different location in memory. My problem though is, how do I handle these labels so that they don't have to be declared before they are called?

At the moment, I'm doing a single step compilation reading straight from the source and outputting the bytecode. I am simply handling labels and adding them to a dictionary when I find them. And then I replace 'otherlabel' with a jump command to the correct location in code. But in this case that code wouldn't compile.

I've thought of a few ways to do this:

First is handling labels before anything else but this requires me to do everything in two steps and I have to deal with the same code twice, this slows down the process and just seems like a mess.

Second is queueing up the label calls until AFTER I've gone through the entire file and compiled everything else and then dealing with them, this seems much cleaner.

I'm writing this in C so I'd rather not implement complex data structures, I'm looking for the most straight forward way to handle this.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're writing your own scripting language instead of using an established language (Perl, Python, Ruby, etc, etc)?

Comment: For fun/experimenting a bit. In a real environment, yes I'd be using Ruby, Python, or Lua etc. depending on my needs, but this is just a little project that I'm having fun with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use multiple passes. One pass isn't going to suffice for a scripting language, especially when you are getting to the more complex structures.

In a first pass, before compiling, construct your dictionary of labels.
In a later pass, when the compiling happens, just use that dictionary.

Comment: Perhaps I'll have to do this, I was just wondering if there was a totally ingenious clean way of doing this I somehow was not thinking about.

Comment: @Matthew Blanchar: How would a program that is only allowed to loop over a file once (AKA live once) look ahead for label names (AKA time travel to the future)?

Comment: I was not thinking that'd be the solution, but time travelling would be a pretty cool way of handling this (perhaps in a few years). I was more meaning there might be an established algorithm or way of handling this as there are for many other things.

Comment: The standard way of doing this in "one pass" is collecting a list of all branch instructions and a list with all lables while you read the file to the end, you can spit out code allready in this pass, e.g. for all branches you branch to FFFF. Every time you find a label to put into the labels list, you already know its "address" noa. Then you have a follow up pass, not really a pass, where you go over your list of branches and check for the existing label, you simply replace the already generated FFFF by the lables address.

Answer (score 4):

You could use "backpatching", although it sounds like that's what you've tried already; and it could be consstrued as a complex structure.

When you encounter a call to an undefined label, you emit the jump with a blank address field (probably into a buffer, otherwise this becomes the same as "multipass" if you have to re-read the file to patch it); and you also store a pointer to the blank field in a "patch-up" list in the dictionary. When you encounter the label definition, you fill-in all the blanks in the list, and proceed normally.

Comment: I actually like this, I being an idiot hadn't thought of doing this, but I did do similar. I like this because it's all done in one loop, and the language is very simple. +1 my boy.

Comment: Oh-- and I don't think this would use any particular complicated structure so much so as to put me off. I was more meaning really high level containers and other things I do not want to spend time implementing. My plan is to use this 'compiler' I'm writing to write a compiler in the language itself, only the virtual machine/interpreter will remain in C, so I didn't want to waste a ton of time on writing this up.

Comment: Well, complexities may arise in the implementation. If you use an explicit buffer, that may complicate code-generation. But you could use a "rw" output file and `ftell(OUTFILE)` to take a "pointer"; `fseek(OUTFILE, ptr, SEEK_SET); fputc(address,OUTFILE); fseek(OUTFILE, 0, SEEK_END);` to do the patch. That only complicates the code. :)